# Disable Recursion in Ruby to Force Use of Y Combinator

Tags: ruby, recursion, metaprogramming, y-combinator

How can Ruby's recursion be 'sabotaged' to disable the ability of ruby methods to engage in recursion?

Needed for the creation of a program to teach lambda calculus, but using Ruby.

Motivation from Crockford on JavaScript - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM&feature=youtu.be&t=1h9m53s

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Even if it existed, it’s application would break nearly 102% of core ruby functionality.

Comment: Just have the method in question not call itself?  (If an existing method you don't control cals itself, and you were somehow able to 'turn off' recursion, the best that you could hope for would be for the method to raise an exception. It certainly would not perform its purpose...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html) API to trace all method calls and returns and build a stack to see whether a method that is called is already on the stack. That way, you can at least *detect* recursion, and then you can just `raise` an exception or `exit` the program.

Something like:

```ruby
stack = []

TracePoint.trace(:call, :return) do |trace|
  p trace, stack
  method = trace.method_id
  case trace.event
  when :call
    if stack.include?(method)
      $stderr.puts "RECURSION DETECTED: method `#{stack.last}` calls method `#{method}`."
      exit!
    end
    stack.push(method)
  when :return
    stack.pop
  end 
end

def foo; bar end
def bar; baz end
def baz; qux end
def qux; bar end

foo
```

Note that I stuck a debug `p`rint in there so that you can observe how it works:

```
#<TracePoint:call `foo'@./test.rb:20>
[]
#<TracePoint:call `bar'@./test.rb:21>
[:foo]
#<TracePoint:call `baz'@./test.rb:22>
[:foo, :bar]
#<TracePoint:call `qux'@./test.rb:23>
[:foo, :bar, :baz]
#<TracePoint:call `bar'@./test.rb:21>
[:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux]
RECURSION DETECTED: method `qux` calls method `bar`.
```